# importing list of 1,000 301 directs into an IIS server?

Tags: .htaccess, iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a list of 1,000 or so 301 redirects. The original format is XML. I was able to convert it to a .htaccess style redirect list but ended up discovering we'd be using IIS so that will not be as useful, however now I do have two formats of the data.  I Would like to be able to quickly import this into IIS. I have installed url-rewrite2.0 and have tried the import mod_rewrite tool but that didn't do anything for the 301 redirects, it just says '0 of 0 imported'.

Can anyone recommend a solid trick to get these into IIS?  I  would like to be able to repeat this in the future so some level of automation would me much better than manually entering 1,000 entries into individual new blank rules.

Also, is url-rewrite the ideal IIS tool to even be managing 301 redirects?  Should I be looking at something else?

examples of current 301 redirect data:

.htacces:
RedirectMatch 301   mail/   http://www.outlook.com/domain.com

xml:
<redirect id="redirects/907" from="email/" to="http://www.outlook.com/domain.com" /

I have tried importing via an htaccess file via the mod_rewrite rules importer of url rewrites. I was hoping it would have imported all of the redirects, but nothing happened.

Comment: "The original format is XML. I was able to convert it to a .htaccess style redirect" then you might convert from the original XML to URL Rewrite rules. This article on rewrite maps might help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module

Comment: In your redirect example, what URL are you redirecting to where? I didn't understand the rules you wrote.

Comment: The URL rewrite module can convert Apache mod_rewrite rules into functionally equivalent IIS URL rewrite rules. However, due to architectural differences between Apache and IIS, not all mod_rewrite rules can be converted. It is strongly recommended that you study the mod_rewrite ruleset until you understand its capabilities before starting the conversion process. Note that only rules that follow the Apache mod_rewrite syntax can be converted. Any other format or incorrectly formatted rewrite rules will not be recognized or will be converted incorrectly.